# Simplest way to batch append string to filenames in directory in macOS command line

Tags: macos, file, command-line-interface, zsh

On a mac terminal,
Given files

```
a 
b
c
```

I'd like batch rename the files to

```
a.csv 
b.csv 
c.csv
```

without installing extra tools.  What is the best way?

Of course there are tools you can install to do this but I'd like to use a simple one liner.

Comment: `mv a a.csv; mv b b.csv; mv c c.csv` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your files' directory:

`for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i}.csv"; done`

Answer (score 1):

The [`zmv` utility](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) that comes with `zsh` works well for tasks like this:

```bash
autoload zmv  # only needed once, can be added to ~/.zshrc
zmv -W '*' '*.csv'
```

The 'from' pattern can be set to match just some files:

```bash
zmv -W '[abc]' '*.csv'
```

The batch rename function in macOS Finder can also be used to rename a set of files. Select the files in Finder, then right click, select `Rename...`, and then select `Add Text`.